# Events and windows forms in C#

Tags: c#, windows

So I just read through the Events tutorial on MSDN and am having some problems applying it in my program.  I was wondering if someone here could give me a hand.

So I have two forms, a parent called `frmInventory` and a child called `frmNewProduct`.  The child has a button called `btnAccept`.  Currently, there is a single subscriber called `btnAccept_Click` subscribed to this event. The existing subscriber is on the child form.  I want to add a second subscriber to this event, but this subscriber will be on the parent form.  Here is the function on my parent form:

```
public void updateInventoryFromChild(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Not sure how to get this working either, but that is another story
    _inventroy = (frmNewProduct)sender._inventory
}
```

And here is my attempt to subscribe the function to my child's event:

```
this.btnAccept.Click += new System.EventHandler((frmInventory)this.Parent.updateInventoryFromChild);
```

Comment: Do you want the click event to be triggered on the parent form?

Comment: I want the event to be triggered when a specific button is clicked on the child form.  What does it mean to be triggered on the parent form?  I think the answer is yes.

Comment: What are the problems you are having?  Are you getting errors?  Is the event not firing on the parent form?  Also, how are you opening the child form, with Show() or ShowDialog()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I stated in one of your previous posts, I think ShowDialog() would be better, for example:

```
class ChildForm : Form {
    private Inventory _inventory;

    public Inventory MyInventory {
        get {
            return _inventory;
        }
    }

    private void btnAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        _inventory = <set_inventory_here>;
        DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

..in your parent form..

```
public void updateInventoryFromChild(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChildForm childForm = new ChildForm();
    if (childForm.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
        _inventory = childForm.MyInventory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have the below code in the child form's constructor!

```
this.btnAccept.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Parent.updateInventoryFromChild);
```

Comment: Right now, I am doing it in the InitializeComponent function that is standard to all Forms.  Is that not adequate?

Comment: @user1556487 you should do it after the call to InitializeComponent!